# Post action API with object parameter within the URL

Tags: javascript, api, react-native

I've got an API where some of the parameters need to be given within the URL.
Example of how my api url looks like: `https://www.server.com/api/actions/execute?auth_type=apikey&data={"Name": "name","Email" : "email"}`

What my code looks like right now

```
register = async () => {
    let data = {"Name":this.state.name, "Email":this.state.email}
    data = JSON.stringify(data)

    let URL = 'https://www.server.com/api/actions/execute?auth_type=apikey&data=';

    fetch(URL, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: new Headers({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }),
      body: data
      })
      .then((response) => response.text())
      .then((responseText) => {
        alert(responseText);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
          console.error(error);
    });
  }
```

The response I get on my device:

```
{"code":"succes","details":{"userMessage":["java.lang.Object@2e56000c"],"output_type":void","id:"20620000000018001"},"message":"function executed succesfully"}
```

This is alle working fine when I test it in postman but I can't get it to work within React-Native. I've tried stuff like `'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'` already.

Comment: how you are accessing the api's in postman ??

Comment: `I can't get it to work within React-Native` . What are the errors ? what the console shows ?

Comment: GET parameters are in the URL, POST parameters in the request body. When you send a POST request, you can also put GET params in the URL. So which is it? The URL at the start of the question has JSON as GET param `data`, but the fetch code below puts the JSON in the request body. Did you mean to use `fetch(URL + data).then(r => r.json()).then(r => console.log(JSON.stringify(r)));`

Comment: share your details, how you have accessed the api's in postman, so that we can work on react native aspects

Comment: Is it ok for you to change system to axios , If so I can give you a working code with Authentication key

Comment: In postman i have set the method to post and enter `https://www.server.com/api/actions/execute?` in the URL bar. Within the params tab I set the query params: `key: authtype with value: apikey` and `key: data with value:{"Name":'test', "Email":'test'}`

Comment: The `Params` button at the end of the URL field sets GET params, regardless of the request method. To set POST params, you need the `Body` tab below. However since your postman test works, the API *does* expect the JSON data in the URL (i.e. as GET param), as your question states. So all you need to do is change the code like I suggested and append `data` to the URL instead of putting it in the request `body`. (of course, a better way would be to change your API instead to expect the JSON in the body, as POST param)

Comment: @MaximeGirou this is what the console shows if I log the response https://shrib.com/#p4s-snTq2TTKt522UaQA

Comment: @Ajith I've tried this with axios: 
`await axios.post(URL,null,{params:data})
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response)
      console.log(response.data);
    })`
If you can explain me what or where I did wrong and how I can make it work within axios sure

Comment: @Raoul Did that work for you , I have given a working code, Can you try debugging on the server side ?

Comment: @ChrisG I've tried your code but It gives me this error: `[Unhandled promise rejection: SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token '<']` Not sure why

Comment: In that case the reply is HTML, not JSON, and the parser complains. Try this instead for now: `fetch(URL + data).then(r => r.text()).then(r => console.log(r));` **The key is to make a request to `URL + data`.** Everything else is details.

Comment: @ChrisG When using the `fetch(URL + data).then(r => r.text()).then(r => console.log(r))` the console responds with a `HTTP Status 400 – Bad Request`. I've tried adding a method and/or a header too, always the same error. I've also checked the composed URL (of URL+data). It gives the exact correct URL so that's not the issue. I do know your method is the correct way to approach this problem though.

Comment: Ah, sorry, you're supposed to use GET params only but the API still expects a POST request, so I guess you need `fetch(URL + data, { method: 'post' })...`

Comment: @ChrisG Somehow that still gave me the same error, while I think that your answers should have worked. But yours answers got me thinking and I compared the two codes of the GET and POST function of the api and I saw the POST function was missing a Return.(The API came from externally so I didn't create it but I asked if I could see what happend in the code) After I edited the code I was able to send the parameters within the body (as x-www-urlencoded). Then I was able to get it working. Thanks for you help though!

Answer (score 0):

First install the package axios from the url https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-axios
Then create two service for handling get and post request so that you can reuse them

GetService.js

```
import axios from 'axios'; 
let constant = {
    baseurl:'https://www.sampleurl.com/'
};
let config = {

    headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    'Accept': 'application/json'
    }
};

export const GetService = (data,Path,jwtKey) => {
    if(jwtKey != ''){
        axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer '+jwtKey;
    }

    try{
        return axios.get(
                            constant.baseUrl+'api/'+Path, 
                            data, 
                            config
                        );
    }catch(error){
        console.warn(error);
    }
}
```

PostService.js

```
import axios from 'axios'; 
let constant = {
    baseurl:'https://www.sampleurl.com/'
};
let config = {

    headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    'Accept': 'application/json'
    }
};

export const PostService = (data,Path,jwtKey) => {
    if(jwtKey != ''){
        axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer '+jwtKey;
    }

    try{
        return axios.post(
                            constant.baseUrl+'api/'+Path, 
                            data, 
                            config
                        );
    }catch(error){
        console.warn(error);
    }
}
```

Sample code for using get and post services is given below

```
import { PostService } from './PostService';
import { GetService } from './GetService';


let uploadData = new FormData();
uploadData.append('key1', this.state.value1);
uploadData.append('key2', this.state.value2);
//uploadData.append('uploads', { type: data.mime, uri: data.path, name: "samples" });

let jwtKey = ''; // Authentication key can be added here
PostService(uploadData, 'postUser.php', jwtKey).then((resp) => {
this.setState({ uploading: false });
    // resp.data will contain json data from server
}).catch(err => {
    // handle error here
});



GetService({}, 'getUser.php?uid='+uid, jwtKey).then((resp) => {
    // resp.data will contain json data from server
}).catch(err => {
    // handle error here
});
```

Comment: There's no need for `axios` at all. And this question is about sending the expected result from the client-side, not rewriting the server API.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to pass parameters via URL you should use GET, if you use POST then the parameters should be passed in the `body`