# axios.post returns bad request of 400 React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, axios, expo

I'm getting my token from an API but unfortunately my API is returning 400 bad request. I've already checked my api via Postman and it's working fine there. Kindly let me know  solution or any mistake.

```
async componentWillMount(){
 axios.post('http://api.myapiurl.com/token', {
                grant_type: 'PASSWORD',
                username: 'MY_USERNAME',
                password: 'MY_PASSWORD'
            }, {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
                }
            }).then(response => {
                console.log(response.data)
            }).catch(err => console.log("api Erorr: ", err.message))
}
```

error in response below

> Request failed with status code 400
>   - node_modules\axios\lib\core\createError.js:16:24 in createError
>   - node_modules\axios\lib\core\settle.js:18:6 in settle
>   - ... 10 more stack frames from framework internals

[image: Postman Screenshot]

Comment: You need to check on logs on server to see why 400 and fix that. With just the frontend code, we will not be able to tell what the server requires.

Comment: @Zaln KhAn you must be getting something in response error. check that because what error are you facing we can't find with this code.

Comment: The axios document says to send the params for `www-form-urlencoded` in a different way. Are you following that ?? 
https://github.com/axios/axios#using-applicationx-www-form-urlencoded-format

Comment: updated please check.

Comment: By default, the params you send will be parsed to json. To send it in `www-form-urlencoded`, you need to follow the documentation.

Comment: I tried to send data into `JSON.stringify(obj)` but not works

Comment: try not adding headers object, remove this:  {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
            }

Comment: can you just post the curl of the postman ?

Comment: @Sushilzzz I tried but not works.

Comment: what do u send in postman, can u send pic ?

Comment: @Sushilzzz updated please check

Comment: ur code seems correct, dont put in headers object as i told u and console.log(response) only, not response.data. there might be error in axios library u installed if not try using fetch()

Comment: @Sushilzzz just tried but not works.

Comment: and I'm calling the service in `async componentWillMount(){}`

Comment: posted a fetch example, try that, should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is Solved by using `QueryString.stringify()`. I just pass the body into `QueryString.stringify()` like below:

```
axios.post('http://api.apiurl.com/token', QueryString.stringify({
            grant_type: 'MY_GRANT_TYPE',
            username: 'MY_USERNAME',
            password: 'MY_PASSWORD'
        }), {
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            }
        }).then(response => {
            console.log(response.data)
        }).catch(err => console.log("api Erorr: ", err.response))
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see you are sending json data, but your `Content-Type` header is set to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`. if your api is expecting json then it should be `application/json`.

Comment: what is your api expecting? json or FromData?

Comment: I'm getting the data in the form of JSON

Answer (score 1):

try using fetch instead, might be some axios bug, you dont need to add any libraries, here is an example:

```
fetch("http://api.myapiurl.com/token", {
  method: "POST", // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    grant_type: "PASSWORD",
    username: "MY_USERNAME",
    password: "MY_PASSWORD"
  }) 
})
  .then(res => {
    res.json();
  })
  .then(data => console.log(data))  // ur data is here
  .catch(err => console.log("api Erorr: ", err));
```

Comment: can I get data using fetch in react native expo app?

Comment: Did you figure out whats happening?

Answer (score 0):

First install the package axios from the url https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-axios
Then create two service for handling get and post request so that you can reuse them

GetService.js

```
import axios from 'axios'; 
let constant = {
    baseurl:'https://www.sampleurl.com/'
};
let config = {

    headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    'Accept': 'application/json'
    }
};

export const GetService = (data,Path,jwtKey) => {
    if(jwtKey != ''){
        axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer '+jwtKey;
    }

    try{
        return axios.get(
                            constant.baseUrl+'api/'+Path, 
                            data, 
                            config
                        );
    }catch(error){
        console.warn(error);
    }
}
```

PostService.js

```
import axios from 'axios'; 
let constant = {
    baseurl:'https://www.sampleurl.com/'
};
let config = {

    headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    'Accept': 'application/json'
    }
};

export const PostService = (data,Path,jwtKey) => {
    if(jwtKey != ''){
        axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer '+jwtKey;
    }

    try{
        return axios.post(
                            constant.baseUrl+'api/'+Path, 
                            data, 
                            config
                        );
    }catch(error){
        console.warn(error);
    }
}
```

Sample code for using get and post services is given below

```
import { PostService } from './PostService';
import { GetService } from './GetService';


let uploadData = new FormData();
uploadData.append('key1', this.state.value1);
uploadData.append('key2', this.state.value2);
//uploadData.append('uploads', { type: data.mime, uri: data.path, name: "samples" });

let jwtKey = ''; // Authentication key can be added here
PostService(uploadData, 'postUser.php', jwtKey).then((resp) => {
this.setState({ uploading: false });
    // resp.data will contain json data from server
}).catch(err => {
    // handle error here
});



GetService({}, 'getUser.php?uid='+uid, jwtKey).then((resp) => {
    // resp.data will contain json data from server
}).catch(err => {
    // handle error here
});
```

Reference from one of my another post [Post action API with object parameter within the URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58951042/post-action-api-with-object-parameter-within-the-url)
If you have any doubts, feel free to know